# Binary search with lower_bound function

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am using the lower_bound function so that an iterator is returned instead of a boolean.

```
auto testPair = make_pair(0, 0);
auto it3 = std::lower_bound(vec[1].begin(), vec[1].end(), testPair, [](const std::pair<int, double> a, const std::pair<int, double> b)
{
    return a.first < b.first;
});
if (it3 != vec[1].end() && !(testPair.first < it3->first))
    vec[1].erase(it3);
```

I basally took the original implementation and changed it so that it returns an iterator so that I can use pairs.

My question is on the following line:

```
if (it3 != vec[1].end() && !(testPair.first < it3->first))
```

My feeling is that the second logical statement could be removed because by using lower_bound it should mean that testPair.first should never be greater than it3->first. However if I remove that part of the if statement it does not work properly in some scenarios.

Could anyone insight me on why this is and why it is needed?

if i pass a pair of

```
    auto testPair = make_pair(0, 0);
```

into a vector of pairs which hold the following

```
std::push_back(std::make_pair(1,1.6));
std::push_back(std::make_pair(2,1.7));
```

it will remove the second pair when it should not remove any.

Comment: Please add more details on the scenarios when it does not work.

Comment: *I have written a lower_bound function so that an iterator is returned instead of a boolean.* uh.... [lower_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) already returns an iterator...

Comment: What does using pairs have to do with anything? The normal `lower_bound` should just work.

Comment: @molbdnilo pairs does not have anything to do with it im just confused on the last logical if statement,

Comment: @Borgleader sorry i mean used.

Comment: `testPair.first` can't be greater than `it3->first`, but it can be "not less than" under some relation given by `operator<`. Note that "not less than and not greater than" is not necessarily the same as comparing equal (with `==`).

Comment: It also appears that your input isn't ordered in accordance with the relation you're passing to `lower_bound`, and that won't work too well.

Comment: @molbdnilo my application it is ordered. i can change it here also to make it more easy to understand.

Comment: In your example it _should_ in fact delete the first pair. `lower_bound` does not search for a particular value, it searches for the first that is not less that the given value.

Comment: Did you try `std::upper_bound` ?

Comment: After `lower_bound`, we know that either `it3 == vec[1].end()` or `!(it3->first < testPair.first)` holds. From the second, we cannot conclude `it3->first == testPair.first`, however we assume that `!(a < b) && !(b < a)` implies `a == b`. By adding the test `!(testPair.first < it3->first)`, we add essentially a test for equality while not requiring another operator. (It isn't exactly equality here, but the relation `a.first == b.first`.)

Comment: @dyp ah I see, I understand now it is the same as using the equality operator. Just wondering why this was not used as it would be easier to understand.

Comment: @ShamariCampbell *"Just wondering why this was not used"* Generic programming tries to maintain minimal requirements on the types involved. Since we already need `<` for the binary search, and it is sufficient for this last step, no additional `==` (which corresponds to yet another function object such as the lambda you've passed) is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algorithm `std::lower_bound` returns iterator before which the target value can be inserted in the sequence such a way that the sequence would be still ordered. This does not mean that the algorithm always returns iterator that points to an element with the same target value.

For example if you have a sequence like

```
{ 0, 2, 4, 6 }
```

and use the algorithm for value 3 then it will return the iterator that points to 4. The sequence does not have the element with value 3. 
So you should check yourself whether the iterator points to an element that has the same value.

For objects of type int as in your example you could write simply

```
if ( it3 != vec[1].end() && testPair.first == it3->first )
                                           ^^^
```

But in general (as for example when float numbers are used) it is better to use operator < because it is this operator is usually used to sort sequences. For example there is no need to declare operator == in your class to sort a sequence of objects of your class by means of operator < and then to use algorithm std::lower_bound to find the target element

In fact for your code snippet this statement

```
if (it3 != vec[1].end() && !(testPair.first < it3->first))
```

is equivalent to the above statement. `testPair.first` can not be greater than `it3->first`. At the same time if it is not less than `it3->first` then you may conclude that they are equal.